# Can't resolve 'kotlin' in '/home/marcin/Projects/EduKotlinAcademy/web/build/node_modules_imported/kotlinx-html-js'

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I started Kotlin/JS react library on kotlin frontend Gradle plugin. I have the following error:

```
> Task :web:webpack-bundle FAILED
js/kotlinx-html-js.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kotlin' in '/home/marcin/Projects/EduKotlinAcademy/web/build/node_modules_imported/kotlinx-html-js'
 @ ../node_modules_imported/kotlinx-html-js/kotlinx-html-js.js 3:4-42
 @ ../node_modules_imported/kotlin-react-dom/kotlin-react-dom.js
 @ ./web.js


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':web:webpack-bundle'.
> node webpack.js failed (exit code = 2)
```

It looks like dependency to Kotlin can't be found on kotlinx-html-js. Although I define Kotlin and it should be generated fine.

For this configuration:

```
group "org.kotlinacademy" version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js' 
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend'

repositories {
    jcenter() 
}

kotlinFrontend {
    npm {
        dependency("webpack-cli", "v2.0.12")
        dependency("react", "15.6.1")
        dependency("react-dom", "15.6.1")
        dependency("react-router-dom", "4.2.2")
        dependency("jquery")
        dependency("react-markdown")
    }

    sourceMaps = true

    webpackBundle {
        bundleName = "main"
        contentPath = file('src/main/web')
        proxyUrl = "http://localhost:8090"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common-js')
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-js:0.22.5"
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-js:0.6.10") { force = true }
    compile 'org.jetbrains:kotlin-react:16.3.1-pre.27-kotlin-1.2.30'
    compile "org.jetbrains:kotlin-react-dom:16.3.1-pre.27-kotlin-1.2.30" 
}

compileKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
    kotlinOptions.outputFile = "$project.buildDir.path/js/${project.name}.js"
    kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'commonjs'
    kotlinOptions.main = "call" }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a SSCCE to see if the problem exists there too? If so, please post that instead of this seemingly more mature project

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, add:

```
 dependency("kotlin", kotlin_version)
```

To NPM dependencies